# Print multiple of 3 and 5 in bash script

Tags: bash, fizzbuzz

Write a short program that prints each number from 1 to 100 on a new line.
• For each multiple of 3, print "Fizz" instead of the number.
• For each multiple of 5, print "Buzz" instead of the number.
• For numbers which are multiples of both 3 and 5, print "FizzBuzz" instead of the
number.

This what i have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash


*for i in {0..20..5}
do
  echo "Number: $i"
done*
```

but i get this:

```
Number: {0..20..5}
```

Need help

Comment: The syntax of that kind of loop is `for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do list ; done`.  Refer to the `man bash` for more details.

Comment: Assuming that the two asterisks in your code are just a copy-and-paste error, I would conclude from the output you get, that this is not executed by bash, or by a very old version of bash, which does not support the `{...}` construct yet. Put in front of the `for` loop a `echo version=$BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: Indeed, `{x..y..incr}` was added at bash4.0 version, year 2009. So one would assume you're on a mac with the default bash shell.

Comment: You don't want to skip any numbers anyway; you want to consider *every* value of `i` between 1 and 100, then decide whether to print the number itself, "Fizz", or "Buzz". `for i in {1..100}; do ...; done` would be the correct loop (and it would work in `bash` 3, though I would still use StephenC's suggestion to generate the numbers as needed instead of all at once). The real problem is writing the code that goes in the *body* of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If it's on a mac, use `$(seq 0 5 20)` to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do echo "$i"; done | sed -E '0~3s/[0-9]+/Fizz/;0~5s/[0-9]+|$/Buzz/'
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
```

Comment: Why would you use `sed` for an arithmetic problem?

Comment: @chepner It is not clear what OP is asking, so I did each step at a time. 1. Print lines 1-100. 2. Change multiples of 3 to Fizz. 3. Change multiples of 5 to Buzz. 4 Overlaps, print both Fizz and Buzz. Does not exactly seem like an arithmetic problem but rather replacing line numbers with strings